# Classifying the endofunctors of the category $\Delta$ of finite linear orders

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-categories, linear-orders

Is there a theory  of endofunctors of the category $\Delta$ of finite linear orders ?
Can they be classified ? Is there a reference on this ?

Can one  classify endofunctors $T:\Delta\to\Delta$ which give rise to sequences in $sC:=\operatorname{Func}(\Delta^\text{op},C)$
$$X_\bullet\to X_\bullet\circ T \to X_\bullet\times X_\bullet$$
(maybe with some nice properties making $X\circ T$ a path object etc.)?

The motivation for the question is that these endofunctors are sometimes used to define simplicial analogues
of path spaces. I am particularly interested in the "edgewise subdivision" endofunctor,
as explained in Dmitri Pavlov's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428475/).
I quote two comments about this endofunctor.

> This endofunctor is basically a special case of the simplicial join
> construction. See [kerodon.net/tag/016K](https://kerodon.net/tag/016K) and also
> [ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets). [— Dmitri Pavlov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428460/defining-homotopy-via-the-doubling-endofunctor-of-a-simplicial-category#comment1102456_428475)
>
> The endofunctor of simplicial sets induced by precomposition with
> [x2] on \Delta is the case r=2 of the r-fold "edgewise subdivision".
> See section 1 of Bokstedt, Hsiang, Madsen, Invent. Math. 111 (465-540)
> 1993, or section 6.2.1 of Dundas-Goodwillie-McCarthy, "The local
> structure of algebraic K-theory". A conceptual precursor is given in
> appendix 1 of Segal, Invent. Math. 21 (213-221) 1973, with the idea
> being credited to Quillen. [— John Rognes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428460/defining-homotopy-via-the-doubling-endofunctor-of-a-simplicial-category#comment1102479_428475)

Answer (score 6):

See [Edgewise subdivision and simple maps](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/rognes/theses/berg-master.pdf) by Knut Berg (supervised by me), [Generalized edgewise subdivisions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3416) by Katerina Velcheva (supervised by Clark Barwick) and the earlier MathOverflow question [What are the endofunctors on the simplex category?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3697/what-are-the-endofunctors-on-the-simplex-category)

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Is $sd(X)$ a path object, in the sense that there is a sequence of maps $X\to sd(X)\to X\times X)$ with appropriate properties ?
The thesis does not mention this explicitly, and Theorem 7.2.1. rather seems to contradict it (
$\S7.2$ (The natural map $e : sd \implies id$ is unique), Theorem 7.2.1. The natural transformation $e : sd \implies id$ in sSet is unique.)

Comment: I deleted two misguided comments with an incorrect definition of an endofunctor $[0<..<n]\to [0<...<2n]$.